# bootstrap-modal doesn't show the dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in rails application. I tried to show dialog box using bootstrap-modal, but the dialog box doesn't come for me. Here is my view code.

```
<div id="creative_attachment_popup" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Do you eant to continue../p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And simply, I call the js file as

```
 $('#creative_attachment_popup').modal('show');
```

the above code shows only a fade page and dosn't contain any dialog. When I type the above js line in my console it shows the following:

```
<div id=​"creative_attachment_popup" class=​"modal hide fade in ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" role=​"dialog"> <h1 style=​"display:​ block;​" aria-hidden=​"false">​…​</div>​
```

Refer the above code with my html. Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to include jQuery.js before, then bootstrap.js!!

And do not use simplified form of html for script. (like `<script src=""/>` ) you have to close it like `<script src=""></script>` )

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- BootStrap Link -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/linker/styles/vendor/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/linker/js/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Have you called `$('#creative_attachment_popup').modal('show');` after the document is ready?

```
$(function() {
    $('#creative_attachment_popup').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Did you include jQuery.js?
- Did you include bootstrap.js? (You must include jQuery before bootstrap)
- Did you include bootstrap.css?
- Go to Javascript Console of the browser (Firebug/Chrome Dev Tool), make sure there is not any errors.

I copied and pasted your code into a blank page and then added the following head:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I ran

```
$('#creative_attachment_popup').modal('show');
```

The medal popup with everything on it. So I guess you may not include everything (or include something wrong).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Comment: I include all the dependencies as you mentioned. But in my console i found this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'" on "$('.windows').validate()"

Comment: What does this validate() method do? jQuery does not have built-in validate() method. So you may want to delete this line